# How to use the instance name as a string in Modelica code?

Tags: stream, modelica

I have a Modelica simulation model composed by some models connected to each other.
I would like to save some data of some of the model instances in my simulation model at a given time using the built-in function

```
Modelica.Utilities.Streams.writeRealMatrix();
```

To be sure which instance writes which file, I would like to include the instance name in the writeRealMatrix() output file name, e.g., in case I have an instance called myModel, using the name:

myModelOut.mat.

To do this, I need a way to get the instance name and put it into a string.
I know that Modelica allows using instance names in model icons, through a Text record, using the keyword "%name", but I don't know how to do the same in a regular string (I mean outside any record or icon annotation).

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In your case I think the function `getInstanceName()` should be a good approach. Using it will need you to edit the model, but given you are writing information from with the class using `writeRealMatrix()` this shouldn't be an issue.

I have created a small example package with a constant block, that stores its name into `final parameter` of type `String`. The example then writes the string to the console at the termination of the simulation:

```
package GetName

  block ConstantNamed "Generate constant signal of type Real"
    extends Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant;
    final parameter String name = getInstanceName();
  end ConstantNamed;

  model Example
    extends Modelica.Icons.Example;
    ConstantNamed myConst(k=23) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}})));

  equation 
    when terminal() then
      Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print("### Here is the models full path: '" + myConst.name + "'");
    end when;
  end Example;
  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")));
end GetName;
```

This should result in a simulation log containing the path of the instance of `ConstantNamed`, which is `Example.myConst`:

[image: Screenshot of Simulation log]

Note: The print function is added to `Example` in the above code. It could be added to the `ConstantNamed` as well. For the case from the question, the print shouldn't be necessary anyways...

Besides that, in case you are using Dymola, there is the `ModelManagement` library, which contains some functions like `ModelManagement.Structure.AST.Classes.ComponentsInClass`. But these are more intended to be applied from "outside" to a given model.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Markus!
I'd checked among the functions available in Modelica.Utilities.Stream, and did not find getInstanceName(). Now I understand that it is built-in in the language, not in MSL.

I checked your example in both Dymola and OpenModelica, and reproduced your results perfectly.

Good to know also about ModelManagement Library to be used in conjunction with Dymola.
Since I use both Dymola and Openmodelica, I could take advantage of this opportunity when using the first of these tools.
Thanks again.